# slide up jumps to top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have some jQuery accordion sliders that slide down and slide up when clicked to reveal content.
Everything works as it should, but if you click on the same link to slide up the same content, it will jump to the top of the page.

I have

```
return false;
```

to prevent it jumping to the top of the page when another slider is clicked, so not too sure on what to use so that it doesn't jump to the top of the page to slide up the same content.

I've tied to add

```
event.preventDefault();
```

which works, but it breaks in IE9 and IE8.

Here's what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.slider').click(function() {  
    $('.internal').slideUp('normal');
    if ($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
        $(this).addClass('on');
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
         return false;
    }
});
$('.internal').hide();
});
```

HTML Sample:

```
<div class="slider"><a href="#">Slide Link 1</a></div>
<div class="internal">
    Stuff1
</div>
<div class="slider"><a href="#">Slide Link 2</a></div>
<div class="internal">
    Stuff2
</div>
```

Comment: The only way i can think would be to make some kind of transparent object that is down near the bottom of the object being slid up, but the reason it scrolls up is because theres nothing else down there.

Comment: [this answer might help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755770/simple-accordion/11755808#11755808)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to want to prevent the default action of the click event. try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slider').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  
  $('.internal').slideUp('normal');
  if ($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
        $(this).addClass('on');
      $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
       return false;
  }
});
$('.internal').hide();
});
```

Comment: Yep, that works in IE9 and IE8.  Thanks!  I wasn't putting the .click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 2):

the links probably have anchor tags like `<a href="#" ...>`, try to remove `href="#"` and if you still want that looks like a link with pointer cursor, use css:

```
a{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Looks like that did the trick, except something broke in IE8.  Ugh.  Damn legacy browser testing.

Comment: This does work as well.  The only thing is to set the CSS correctly since there is no <a href="#"> in there.  In case anyone else sees this.